# When setting the floating point type in PyTorch, what is the difference between tensor type and dtype, and when should I set one over the other?

Tags: numpy, runtime-error, pytorch

I'm using doubles as my model inputs and outputs, so I am trying to set torch to use float64 instead of float32. What exactly is the difference between

`torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)`

> Sets the default torch.Tensor type to floating point tensor type t. This type will also be used as default floating point type for type inference in torch.tensor().

`torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float64)`

> Sets the default floating point dtype to d. This type will be used as default floating point type for type inference in torch.tensor().

The documentation reads to me that setting the tensor type also sets the dtype, but I am not sure when I would use one over the other.

I should mention that either statement fixes the error that I was seeing after changing from floats to doubles:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 122, in train_model  
    output = net(action)  
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "models.py", line 25, in forward
    return self.fc2(F.relu(self.fc1(x)))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 67, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1352, in linear
    ret = torch.addmm(torch.jit._unwrap_optional(bias), input, weight.t())
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'
```

Comment: I could imagine that `set_default_tensor_type` accepts custom tensor types as well. Looking at the source for [`set_default_tensor_type`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/d70c6f23f40bab5baf88a62cfd045abac4335b39/torch/csrc/tensor/python_tensor.cpp#L361) and [`set_default_dtype`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ada8f828f9c18461333c07a9caa836af175c60bd/c10/core/DefaultDtype.cpp#L7) reveals that they're calling `at::set_default_dtype(default_tensor_type->typeMeta());` anyway so `set_default_tensor_type` is more general. For your example they have probably the same effect.